# Why does [NSLocale currentLocale] return id?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In the header for NSLocale, `currentLocale` is declared like this:

```
+ (id /* NSLocale * */)currentLocale;   // an object representing the user's current locale
```

It's obvious that they are returning `id` on purpose, but I'm curious why that would be necessary. Could this method ever return anything other than an NSLocale instance?

Comment: I suspect that NSLocale is a weakly-defined "class cluster", where the component classes, if interrogated, will not necessarily claim to be subclasses of NSLocale, even though they all respond that way.

Comment: Observe that initWithLocaleIdentifier: is defined like this `- (instancetype)initWithLocaleIdentifier:(NSString *)string`

Comment: so why don't they use instance type for `currentLocale`?

Comment: That's a good question.  I see that `instancetype` is used in other classes, such as NSSet.  Why don't you pose that as a question:  What is the difference between `id` and `instancetype`?

Comment: If [SomeSubClassOfNSLocale currentLocale] returns an instance of anything other than SubSubClassOfNSLocale or one of its subclasses, then instancetype would be inappropriate and misleading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back in the day, one used `NSDictionary` objects for locale information. See, for example, the "Special Considerations" documented for [`-[NSString compare:options:range:locale:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare%3aoptions%3arange%3alocale%3a):

> **Special Considerations**
>
> Prior to OS X v10.5, the *locale* argument was an instance of `NSDictionary`. On OS X v10.5 and later, if you pass an instance of `NSDictionary` the current locale is used instead.

Some methods, such as `-[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:locale:]` still take an `NSDictionary`.

Other methods, such as many classes' `-descriptionWithLocale:`, can take either.

Anyway, with the introduction of `NSLocale` the types of various locale parameters was generalized to `id` to accommodate either kind of object without breaking source compatibility.  The return type of `+[NSLocale currentLocale]` is similar generic so that it can be passed to methods that used to only take `NSDictionary` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Initializers (even convenience initializer) traditionally return `id`. This prevents problems when you subclass. For instance, imagine this scenario:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
- (Foo *)initWithBar:(Bar *)bar;
@end

@interface Baz : Foo
- (Baz *)initWithBar:(Bar *)bar;
@end
```

This would be a compiler error. You are redefining `initWithBar:` to return a different type. But if you always return `Foo*`, then `Baz *baz = [Baz initWithBar:bar]` would fail because `initWithBar:` returns a superclass.

To get yourself out of this problem, all initializers have historically returned `id` if there's any chance the class will be subclassed (which is to say, you should really always do this).

Recently, clang added [`instancetype`](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/), which solves this problem more elegantly by representing "the type of the current class." This is only useable in the interface. You can't declare variables to be of type `instancetype` (I've actually wanted this in some cases…) `id` is automatically promoted to `instancetype` for methods that begin with `init…`. Otherwise, you need to use it manually. Many older Cocoa interfaces haven't been updated yet, but they're slowly moving over to `instancetype`.

Comment: perfect, maybe in iOS 8 currentLocale will see some instancetype love!